# Permission for installing Power BI apps from AppSource

Tags: powerbi

I've set up free Power BI access for myself. Then I've upgraded it into "Pro trial" licence. 
For testing purposes, I was trying to install some Power BI apps from AppSource. 
However - for every app I was trying to do this - the following error message appears:

*This app hasn't been listed on AppSource. You don't have permissions to install this app.*

*Contact your admin about permissions for installing this app.
Apps may contain security or privacy risks. Only install apps from trusted authors and sources. Learn more*

I’m not sure where I should set up additional permission for doing it on my account because my account is Global Admin of organization (and this is the only account set up at this moment).  And the licence which is currently assigned to my account is “PowerBI (free)”

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [Admin portal -> Tennant settings](https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/tenantSettings) and check if `Install template apps` is enabled:

[image]